# Probability space of Banach matchbox problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, negative-binomial

> Suppose a mathematician carries two matchboxes at all times: one in his left pocket and one in his right. Each time he needs a match, he is equally likely to take it from either pocket. Suppose he reaches into his pocket and discovers for the first time that the box picked is empty. If it is assumed that each of the matchboxes originally contained $N$ matches, what is the probability that there are exactly $k$ matches in the other box?

I guess the problem is quite known, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem.

In the solution on wikipedia it says: *"Without loss of generality consider the case where the matchbox in his right pocket has an unlimited number of matches"*.

Why can we simply assume this?

---

My naive guessing is something like that:

We can embed the sample space of the "matchbox experiment" into a bigger sample space, namely the one of a negative binomially distributed random variable, without changing the probabilities. E.g. Let $(L,L,R,R,L)$ denote one possible outcome where each matchbox contains $3$ matches. If I choose between both pockets one more time then $$P((L,L,R,R,L))=P((L,L,R,R,L))\cdot (P(L)+P(R))=P((L,L,R,R,L))\cdot 1=P((L,L,R,R,L)).$$
So the probibility of my original outcome hasn't changed. Keeping this in mind my idea would be to extend this argument to $\infty$ which means I keep on choosing between the two pockets.

Comment: Saying "without loss of generality" is a bit misleading. The idea is that you first consider the case when the right-hand box has an unlimited supply in order to determine the expected number $M$ of removals from the right-hand box under that assumption. Then you calculate probabilities conditional on $M < N + 1$, which implies that $N$ matches in the right-hand box will be sufficient.

Comment: @RobArthan, I don't understand what the unlimited supply has to do with an expected number $M$ and how this would help? But I have edited my question, maybe it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: The assumption of the unlimited supply just allows you to use a standard result to get the expected number of removals from the right-hand box. If you know that the expected number $M$ is less than $N + 1$, then the experiment with the unlimited supply in the right-hand box is the same as the experiment with just $N$ matches in the right-hand box.

Comment: @RobArthan Why is that so? I mean, what is the mathematical reason that allows us to ignore the infinite draws? I don't get it why we can first start with an infinite setting then turn it in something finite and then still can be sure that the result is still valid for our problem?